# SplashScreen - Image from another project cannot be located

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, splash-screen

I try to create a `SplashScreen` with an image from another project:

```
SplashScreen s = new SplashScreen("/MyAssembly;component/myImage.png");
```

Using this resource address works for regular images, but I can't create the `SplashScreen`:

> Cannot locate resource '/MyAssembly;component/myImage.png'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the splashscreen's overloaded constructor: `SplashScreen s = new SplashScreen(assembly, "myImage.png");`

`assembly` can be acquired as `var assembly = Assembly.Load("MyAssembly")` (where `"MyAssembly"` is the full name of your assembly).

Comment: I know how to get the assembly based on a type in it: Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyType))  -- unfortunately I have only pictures in this assembly